# How to deploy a API.AI(Dialog flow) bot on my website?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have created a bot using API.AI. I have a webhook connected to it checking and validating something in DB written in Python running on ngrok in my local.

if I have to call my dialog flow bot on my website, I can do it using API call with giving Client Access token in Node js npm API.AI module. and UI can be generated using BOT UI framework.

Then, What is the use of Developer access token?

Currently I am running everthing on my local, but when i access my bot using api , webhook doesn't trigger. How can i solve that problem. How can i deploy the entire thing on say Heroku.

If possible can you please explain me API call and webhook call in respect to Dialogflow. Is it like i can't use both of them together(confusing).

Comment: If you've found my answer helpful please mark it as correct for others who come across this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Dialogflow's web demo you can add some HTML and have the Dialogflow agent embedded in your website.  It only works with text input/responses at the moment.

Here is an example:

```
<iframe style="float: right;" width="350" height="430" 
   src="https://console.dialogflow.com/api-client/demo/embedded/12f4b5a4-1c0b-4d04-81c0-39a028e2aff0">
 </iframe>
```

Documentation is here: https://dialogflow.com/docs/integrations/web-demo